# Cannot get local JSON data getJSON

Tags: jquery, json

I have a local JSON data file from which I need to extract data. The path is correct and works properly in other files. However it doesnt seem to be working here.

My JSON file is as below:

```
{
    "Phone": {
        "Samsung":[{
          "Size" : "AAA",
          "Camera" : "BBB",
          "Weight" : "CCC"
        }],
        "Apple":[{
            "Size" : "XXX",
            "Camera" : "YYY",
            "Weight" : "ZZZ"
          }]

    }
}
```

My jQuery is as below:

```
<body>
    <div id="AboutTab">
        <div id=About class="OuterFlexContainer">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var StatJSON;
        jQuery.getJSON("/TrialJSON/JSONData/QueryJSONData.json", function (json) {
            StatJSON = json;
            console.log(StatJSON);
    });

var markup = '';
markup += '<div>'+ StatJSON.Phone.Samsung[0].Size +'<div>'
markup += '<div>'+ StatJSON.Phone.Apple[0].Size +'<div>'

    $("#About").html(markup);

});

</script>
```

Where am I going wrong? The JSON path is fine, the error appears to be in the jQuery.

Comment: Hi , put that whole code `var markup = '';
markup += '<div>....$("#About").html(markup);` inside your `getJSON` callback .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `StatJSON` is being populated in the callback to `getJSON`, which means that when you're trying to use `StatJSON` for generating the markup, it hasn't been populated yet.

Try moving the markup generation to inside the callback and it should work,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var StatJSON;
    jQuery.getJSON("/TrialJSON/JSONData/QueryJSONData.json", function (json) {
        StatJSON = json;
        console.log(StatJSON);
        
        var markup = '';
        markup += '<div>'+ StatJSON.Phone.Samsung[0].Size +'<div>'
        markup += '<div>'+ StatJSON.Phone.Apple[0].Size +'<div>'

        $("#About").html(markup);
    });
});
```